# How Do I Define a Global Template Helper Function?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

In many templates I want to use the same functions, but they must defined in every template.
like this:

```
function getNodesById(id){
    return collection.find({sid:id}).fetch();
}

Template.navigation.getNodesById= function(id){
    return getNodesById(id);
}

Template.body.getNodesById= function(id){
    return getNodesById(id);
}
```

Html:

> ```
> <Template name="navigation">
> ... 
> {{#each getNodesById '1'}}
> ...
> {{/each}}
> ...
> </Template>
> <Template name="body">
> ...
> {{#each getNodesById '1'}}
> ...
> {{/each}}
> ...
> </Template>
> ...
> <Template name="...">
>  .....
> </Template>
> ```

Are There any way can defined globle template function instead of  a template ? just like it:
In javascript:

```
    defined global tempele.functionA = function(...){
         return ...
    }
```

in html:

> ```
> <Template name ="a">
>    {{#each  functionA ...}}
>    {{/each }}
> </Template>
>
> <Template name ="b">
>    {{#each  functionA ...}}
>    {{/each }}
> </Template>
> <Template name="...">
>     {{ #..  functionA ...}}
>         ....
>      {{/...}}
> </Template >
> ```

Can I do this? I hope I described the problem clearly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can register your helpers with handlebars directly. This is what I am using for displaying the current users's email address:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('currentUserName', function () {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (_.isUndefined(user) || _.isNull(user)) {
        return new Handlebars.SafeString("<i class='icon-spin icon-spinner'></i> Login");
    }
    return user.emails[0].address;
});
```

In any template I just call `{{currentUserName}}`. For you that'd be

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getNodeById', function (id) {
    return collection.find({sid:id}).fetch();
});
```

As a side note: looking at how you want to use it, you might have gotten the idea of Meteor wrong. Meteor is data-driven - don't try to enforce flow-driven paradigms. If you are missing some data in your templates you should change the data-source, not just fetch it in your templates.

Comment: Thanks  for your remind ,I think I was wrong at start.Meteor is data-driven,I'll keep that in mind。Thank you !

Answer (score 13):

As of Meteor 1.0, the documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Template-registerHelper) instructs developers to use `Template.registerHelper` in order to define globally-available template helpers.

So in the case of this question, the correct code format would be this:

```
    Template.registerHelper("getNodesById", function(id) {
        return collection.find({sid: id});
    }
```

You could then reference this template helper in any of your templates in the following two ways:

```
    {{getNodesById '1'}}
```

or

```
    {{#each getNodesById '1'}}
      ...
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Meteor 0.8 or higher, using `UI.registerHelper` will do the job.